# My List<> returns the exact number of files found BUT displays the same data through the entire loop

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

**PROBLEM:**

In my Program, when I try to loop the entire List of file found, I got exactly the **8 files** on my List BUT displayed the same data value.

**DEFINITION:**
Class:

1.SearchFile.cs = has a method that accepts 2 parameters(**PathToSearch** and **fileExtensionToSearch**) then returns a List of "**FileDetails**" type.

```
    public List<FileDetails> fileListFound = new List<FileDetails>();

    public List<FileDetails> GetListFiles(string strPath, string strFileExtension)
    {

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
        FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles(strFileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails();
        foreach (FileInfo  currentFile in files)
        {
            fileDetails.FileFullName = currentFile.FullName;
            fileDetails.FileFullPath = strPath;

            fileListFound.Add(fileDetails);

        }

        return fileListFound;
    }
```

2.FileDetails.cs

```
 class FileDetails
{
    public string FileFullName { get; set; }
    public string FileFullPath { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }

}
```

1. My Main Program:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string strPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures";

       FileCollection fileCollected = new FileCollection();
       List<FileDetails> listOfFileFound = fileCollected.GetListFiles(strPath, "*.jpg");
       foreach (FileDetails fileFound in listOfFileFound)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Full Name: " + fileFound.FileFullName + ", Path:" + fileFound.FileFullPath);
       }
       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```

NOTE: Im using Console application just to be clear with my Problem.

**Sample Output:** (8 files found)

...\Pictures**Tulips.jpg**

...\Pictures**Tulips.jpg**

...\Pictures**Tulips.jpg**

**etc..** looped 8 times with the same output

**NOTE**: I can tell that the **SearchFile.cs** Class found the 8 **different files** then add it to my **List** and return it successfully by putting some breakpoints (Debug).

Comment: You're adding the same reference each time. This [article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) explains the differences between value and reference types.

Comment: Hi Dave thanks a lot.. I tried to search a long time ago with this topic but cant find any. I really appreciate your recommendation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are always modifying the same instance of `fileDetails`. You need to allocate a new one inside the loop at every iteration:

```
    foreach (FileInfo  currentFile in files)
    {
        FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails();
        fileDetails.FileFullName = currentFile.FullName;
        fileDetails.FileFullPath = strPath;

        fileListFound.Add(fileDetails);

    }
```

Since fileDetails is a reference that gets added to the list, modifying the same instance will cause all the values in the list to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

The `fileDetails` variable represents a class, which means it's a reference type, which means you're simply putting *one* identical item into the list *eight* times - that is, when you set the file details with lines such as,

```
fileDetails.FileFullName = currentFile.FullName;
```

You're just *updating* the class instance data, which will be reflected in each reference.

what you will need to do is create a *new* instance of `FileDetails` per file, as in:

```
foreach (FileInfo  currentFile in files)
{
    fileListFound.Add(
        new FileDetails
        {
            FileFullName  = currentFile.FullName,
            FileFullPath = strPath
        }
    );   
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I noticed a few minutes ago you had like 9999. congrats on hitting 10K. :)

Answer (score 3):

cause you put one instance in all the LIST

Change this:

```
FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails();
        foreach (FileInfo  currentFile in files)
        {
            fileDetails.FileFullName = currentFile.FullName;
            fileDetails.FileFullPath = strPath;

            fileListFound.Add(fileDetails);

        }
```

to this:

```
    foreach (FileInfo  currentFile in files)
    {
        FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails(); // IN THE LOOP

        fileDetails.FileFullName = currentFile.FullName;
        fileDetails.FileFullPath = strPath;

        fileListFound.Add(fileDetails);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create new `FileDetails`  object for every list item. Otherwise you overwrite the same item every loop.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because your foreach loop contains bad code.

You need to re-declare fileDetails on each iteration - what happens is that
all of your fileListFound object contains ONE copy of the object fileDetails, and when you change
the last one - it changes the rest.

Here's the fixed code:

```
public List<FileDetails> fileListFound = new List<FileDetails>();

public List<FileDetails> GetListFiles(string strPath, string strFileExtension)
{

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
    FileInfo[] files = dirInfo.GetFiles(strFileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);


    foreach (FileInfo  currentFile in files)
    {
        FileDetails fileDetails = new FileDetails();
        fileDetails.FileFullName = currentFile.FullName;
        fileDetails.FileFullPath = strPath;

        fileListFound.Add(fileDetails);
    }

    return fileListFound;
}
```